# Android SQLite- View 'raise()' exception messages in Log

Tags: android, sqlite

If I wrote a trigger with a 'then raise(abort, "my error message")' clause for SQLite in an Android app, is there any way to view "my error message" in the LogCat?  I wanted to know if it's at all possible to write my own custom error messages to log rather than have to rely on SQLite's vague error codes when constraints fail.

Thanks.